# How to get data out of nested dictionaries for a table view with sections?

Tags: uitableview, nsdictionary, plist

I'd like to fill a table view with the content of my custom plist file. The table view has to be segmented. I work in Xcode 8 and code in Swift.

I have a plist like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Item0</key>
    <dict>
        <key>SectionKey</key>
        <dict/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

In the web I found a nice description how to create a segmented table view which works fine for me: [Segmented Table View Tutorial](https://www.codebeaulieu.com/34/Creating-a-UITableViewController-with-sections-in-iOS-9)

This example uses a struct like this:

```
struct Section {

var heading: String
var items: [String]

init(title: String, objects: [String]) {

    heading = title
    items = objects
}
```

}

And then it fills the struct with data in this function:

```
func getSectionsFromData() -> [Section] {

    var sectionsArray = [Section]()

    let animals = Section(title: "Animals", objects: ["Cats", "Dogs", "Birds", "Lions"])
    let vehicles = Section(title: "Vehicles", objects: ["Cars", "Boats", "Planes", "Motorcycles", "Trucks"])

    sectionsArray.append(animals)
    sectionsArray.append(vehicles)

    return sectionsArray
}
```

So, my idea is to iterate through my plist (I stored it in a NSMutableDicttionary named dict) to get the data in a way, that I can use this example to get my table view filled in the right way:

```
for i in (0..<dict.count) {

        newDict = dict.object(forKey: "Item\(i)") as! NSMutableDictionary
    }
```

What I get in newDict is a structure which looks like this (these are my three segments: account, credit card and cash). All keys and values are strings:

```
    {
    "Account" =     (
                {
            AmountKey = "Some amount";
            CategoryKey = Some category;
            DateKey = "Some date";
        }
    );
    "Credit card" =     (
                {
            AmountKey = "Some amount";
            CategoryKey = Some category;
            DateKey = "Some date";
        }
    );
    "Cash" =     (
                {
            AmountKey = "Some amount";
            CategoryKey = Some category;
            DateKey = "Some date";
        }
    );
}
```

The question is: How I have to iterate through my dict, to get all entries sorted by account, credit card and cash so that I can use the example above (instead of: let animals = Section(title: "Animals", objects: ["Cats", "Dogs", "Birds", "Lions"]) I get something like this: let account = Section(title: "Account", objects: [["AmountKey": "Some amount", "CategoryKey": "Some category", "DateKey": "Some date"], ["AmountKey": "Some amount", "CategoryKey": "Some category", "DateKey": "Some date"],..].

Thank's Martin

Comment: were you ever able to figure this out Martin, sorry for my late reply

Comment: yes, I changed the structure of my plist and built a suitable solution